# polymorphism and including files couse "No viable overload ="

Tags: c++, graph, overloading

I couldn't find answer, i hope You guys can help me.
I've created two classes 1.GraphMatrix 2.GraphList both of them are in public inheritance with class Graph(virtual class). Then i wanted to overload "=" for classes 1&2. After implementing the second one, the first overloaded "=" stopped working. I think it couse somehow shadowing methods. Can someone explain me why it's happening and how to solve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GrafList.cpp"
#include "Graf.cpp"

int main() {
    GrafMatrix<int,30> Gm;
    Gm.fill(0.5);
    GrafList<int,30> G;
    Gm.fill(1);
   Gm = G;
   G = Gm;
    return 0;
}
```

Header GraphMatrix

```
#include "Graf.cpp"
#include "GrafList.h"

template <class Type, int MAXIMUM>
class GrafMatrix : public Graf<Type,MAXIMUM> {
private:
    int adjacencyMatrix [MAXIMUM][MAXIMUM]{};

public:
    GrafMatrix();
    ~GrafMatrix();

    void addVertex(const Type& value);
    void addEdge(int source, int target, int value = 1);

    void removeEdge(int source, int target);
    void fill(double density,int maxWeight = MAXIMUM);
    void print();
    int GetEdge(int source, int target)const;
    Type& operator [] (int vertex);
    Type operator [] (int vertex)const;
    GrafMatrix &operator =(GrafList<Type,MAXIMUM> &G);
    bool isEdge(int source, int target);
    std::set<int> neighbours(int vertex)const;
};
```

Header GraphList

```
    #include "GrafMatrix.h"
    #include "Graf.cpp"
template <typename Type,int MAXIMUM>
class GrafList:public Graf<Type,MAXIMUM>  {
private:
    std::vector<Edge> Edges;

public:
    GrafList();
    ~GrafList();

    void addVertex(const Type& value);
    void addEdge(int source, int target, int value = 1);
    void removeEdge(int source, int target); 
    void fill(double density,int maxWeight = MAXIMUM);
    void print();
    Type& operator [] (int vertex);
    Type operator [] (int vertex)const;
    GrafList&operator =(GrafMatrix<Type,MAXIMUM> &G);
    bool isEdge(int source, int target);
    std::set<int> neighbours(int vertex)const;


};
```

Comment: including .cpp is wrong

Comment: then im getting undefined reference to methods